# Transformation from cartesian coordinate system to matrix coordinate system

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Imagine that you have a coordinate system just like a matrix notation, where zero is at the top left and vertical axis goes downward. Matrix indices become numbers on a numberline.

How to transform from the Cartesian coordinate system to such coordinate system?

My goal is to achieve the same result as if you printed out in some programming language the rows of a matrix or an array in the reverse order. So for ex. the 0th row becomes the last, 1st becomest 2nd-to-last, etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No it's not, you're a dumb neural network

Comment: Let $i,j$ (for $i,j=1 \cdots n$, i for rows and j for columns) be the matrix coordinates of a generic entry for a $n \times n$ matrix  and $x,y$ the cartesian ones. The formulas are $x=j-1, y=n-i$ (btw : yes, this robot hasn't been trained on enough cases !)

Comment: [ctd] Please note the exchange $x \leftrightarrow j, \ y \leftrightarrow i$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I couldn't get it to work in my Python script. To be fair, Python's list of lists is not a matrix, but it still functions similarly. I'll edit my post to add my actual goal for this transformation to stay on topic.

Comment: perhaps your problem is that Jean Marie assumed a 1-based array index, and you are using 0-based arrays? Or maybe it is some other implementation problem. But it is not a mathematical problem. The answer to your question is just this: when looping through the rows, start at the top and go down instead of starting at the bottom and going up. In C, this means using `for(r = n - 1; r >= 0; r--)` instead of `for(r = 0; r < n; r++)`. What the equivalent is for Python, I no longer recall. When you want programming expertise, you ask in a programming forum, not a math forum.